# kinect 2 C# event type conversion

Tags: c#, events, types, kinect, porting

I am now updating my Kinect program from 1.8 to 2.0 but got problems.

```
    //Please consider the follow code
    public abstract class ISkeletonFrameHandler
    {
        //version 1.8
        //public abstract void FrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e);
        //version 2.0
        public abstract void FrameReady(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e);
    }

    public void AddSkeletonFrameHandler(ISkeletonFrameHandler handler)
    {
        if (this.IsSkeletonStreamReady)
        {
            try
            {

                //SDK 1.8 below is not problem
                //this.Sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(handler.FrameReady);
                //SDK 2.0 below get error CS0029, cannot convert type to type   
                this.Sensor.BodyFrameSource.FrameCaptured += new EventHandler<BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs>(handler.FrameReady);
                 }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
        Event.Track("Fail to start the skeleton event handler!", Event.Type.Warning, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I change the event statement to avoid error?

Comment: `cannot convert type to type`  - which type to which one? The error should also print that types.

Comment: The error code is " CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<Microsoft.Kinect.BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs>' to 'System.EventHandler<Microsoft.Kinect.FrameCapturedEventArgs>'"

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing as `SkeletonFrame` in Kinect 2. In kinect 2 `BodyFrame` provides skeletal data. Remember that, just because `BodyFrame` provides the skeletal data doesn't mean it is same as `SkeletonFrame`. There are a lot of difference in class structures and data.

Now, I think, `this.Sensor.BodyFrameSource.FrameCaptured += new EventHandler<BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs>(handler.FrameReady);` this line of your program is responsible for the error you mentioned.

> The error code is " CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.EventHandler<Microsoft.Kinect.BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs>` to
>   `System.EventHandler<Microsoft.Kinect.FrameCapturedEventArgs>`

Write `this.Sensor.BodyFrameSource.FrameCaptured` and then write `+=`. Visual studio should suggest intellisence, if it doesn't, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> then visual studio should show the suggestion.

[image]

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to insert. Visual Studio Intellisence should automatically suggest you to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to generate the method stub. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The method stub will be generated.

[image]

Write your event handler code inside the generated method.

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: In short, how can we rewrite the following code to version 2?

Comment: public abstract class ISkeletonFrameHandler {public abstract void FrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e);}
public void AddSkeletonFrameHandler(ISkeletonFrameHandler handler) { this.Sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(handler.FrameReady);}